# FirebaseViewController is black

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

when following the instructions for FirebaseUI to display the LoginViewController it only shows a black screen.[image: black screen]
As you can see it kind of replaces the current viewcontroller instead of presenting it.

Here is the code from the presenting viewcontroller

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var logoutButton: UIButton!

    var rootRef = Firebase(url: Constants.FireBaseUrl)
    var loginViewController: FirebaseLoginViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginViewController = FirebaseLoginViewController(ref: rootRef)
        loginViewController.enableProvider(.Facebook)
        loginViewController.enableProvider(.Password)
        loginViewController.didDismissWithBlock { (user: FAuthData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (user != nil) {
                // user
            } else if (error != nil) {
                // error
            } else {
                // cancel
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if (loginViewController.currentUser() == nil) {
        presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func logoutTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
        rootRef.unauth()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is loginViewController.enableProvider(.Facebook) supposed to be loginViewController.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Facebook)? There's a couple of other differences between this code and the tutorial code. You may want to compare the two. I may be overlooking something but why is the FAuthData(!) being force unwrapped?

Comment: do you have any resolution on this? I'm seeing the same issue

Comment: Same issue here. @zeiteisen did you solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue... @zeiteisen any news?

Comment: Please upvote if you have the same issue.